# Does attempting to activate a wand count as an attack for invisibility?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, magic-items, invisibility

Does attempting to activate a wand count as an attack for the purpose of breaking invisibility?

Context is my ninja using vanishing trick, if i attempt to activate a wand of scorching ray (or other damage based spell) does that break my invisibility if i a) fail the check? b) Pass but decide not to use the wand.

I'm reading it as a preparatory action and not an actual attack as the dc check couldnt inflict damage, i could pass the check and then not use the wand?

Thankyou

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't think you can pass the check and then not use the wand.  You can't make the check in advance and then hold it until you want to fire it;  you don't roll the UMD dice until you actually try to activate the wand and cast the spell inside it.  However, in the case of a failure, no attack has really been made, so I suppose it wouldn't break *[invisibility](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/coreRulebook/spells/invisibility.html#invisibility)*.

The closest physical action I can equate this to is a crossbow or firearm that you forgot to reload.  You aim, you pull the trigger, and nothing happens.  There was an intent to attack, but no attack.  A *missed* attack (you activate the wand/pull the trigger, but miss with the *scorching ray*/bullet) is still an attack and would break your *invisibility*, but just meaning to attack and failing to - the intent isn't something the spell should react to, since just waving a wand isn't an attack.  Without the spell going off, the *invisibility* spell can't know if you were targeting an enemy or an ally, or even yourself with some sort of buff or heal spell.  Until the *scorching ray* actually jumps out at an enemy, you haven't made an attack and thus shouldn't be subject to your spell ending early.

Comment: I really wish I could find a hard rules reference for this somewhere, but I don't think I'm going to come up with one;  this answer feels right to me, though, so here you are.  Hope it helps.

Comment: Another analogy is all the times in Harry Potter classes someone _tries_ to cast a spell, swishes and flicks and says the magic words, and absolutely nothing happens.

Comment: The criterion for invisibility is "target an enemy" vs "target an ally", not harm vs buff. And if you fail to cast a spell, then you haven't targeted anything.

Comment: @topquark you are indeed correct.  I've been arguing these cases for so long I automatically remembered the 3.5 definition, where they said attack but didn't define it the way PF does.